# Конструктор с самовызывающейся функцией

Tags: javascript

```
var Cat = (function () {

    var message = 'name or weight not specified when invoking the constructor';

    function Cat(name, weight) {

        if (name === undefined || weight === undefined){
            throw new Error(message);
        }
         this.name = name;
         this.weight = weight;
     }
     Object.defineProperty(this, "averageWeight",{
            get: function(){ return this.weight; },
            //set: function(value){ this.weight = value; }
        });

   return Cat;
}());



console.log(Cat);

var fluffy = new Cat('fluffy',15);
console.log(fluffy);

console.log(typeof Cat.averageWeight); // function, выдает undefined

console.log(fluffy.averageWeight); // undefined, выдает undefined 

console.log(Cat.averageWeight()); // 20, выдает ошибку
```

Подскажите как правильно задать свойство "averageWeight", чтобы console.log(typeof Cat.averageWeight) было function, a Cat.averageWeight() работало как функция

Comment: вместо `get` используйте `value`

Comment: нужно обязательно использовать Object.defineProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать `value` на `Cat.prototype` для этого.
В примере, определена функция, которая без параметров работает как геттер, а с параметром, как сеттер. (Такие функции довольно привычны в `jQuery`)

```
Object.defineProperty(Cat.prototype, "averageWeight",{
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(value){ 
      if(typeof value == 'undefined') return this.weight;
      this.weigth = value;
      return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо,все работает

Comment: у тебя _typeof Cat.averageWeight_ - не `function`. Странно почему автор вопроса принял ответ :-) либо он написал неверные требования.